# Regex for extracting time from natural language string

Tags: javascript, regex, time

Inside my logic I need a string var to be persisted in database, that string is in fact some sort of time format customized toString variable on the following way:

```
(days)d(hours)h(minutes)m
```

example 2 days 15 hours and half =>`2d15h30m`

I would like to make sure no one trolls on the text input expecting that format to be submitted and giving another one, I've always been awful building patterns and regex can someone please help me quickly with this one?

I've tried myself:

```
([0-9]{1}|[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{1})d([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}|20|21|22|23)h([0-5]{1}|[0-9]{1})m
```

But it didn't work out, just like everytime I try to build one of those.

Comment: `(\d+)d([01]?\d|2[0-3])h([0-5]?\d)m`

Comment: I think you may use `pattern="\d+d(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3])h[0-5]?\dm"`. Is `0d0h0m` valid?

Comment: Hey thanks to both for that quick answer, no 0d0h0m its the only result it can't be possible, atleast it should contain 1 minute (0d0h1m) i forgot to say that sorry... I'm not used to ask here I'll improve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern="(?=[^1-9]*[1-9])\d+d(?:[10]?[0-9]|2[0-3])h[0-5]?\dm"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wVGgkP/1/) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A(%3F%3D%5B%5E1-9%5D*%5B1-9%5D)%5Cd%2Bd(%3F%3A%5B10%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7C2%5B0-3%5D)h%5B0-5%5D%3F%5Cdm)%24):

[image]

In a HTML5 `pattern` attribute regex, this pattern will be used to compile the following regex: `^(?:(?=[^1-9]*[1-9])\d+d(?:[10]?[0-9]|2[0-3])h[0-5]?\dm)$`.

It matches

- `^(?:` - start of string and the start of a non-capturing container group
- `(?=[^1-9]*[1-9])` - a positive lookahead that requires at least one non-zero digit in the input
- `\d+d` - 1+ digits and a `d` char after
- `(?:[10]?[0-9]|2[0-3])h` - an optional `1` or `0` followed with a digit, or `2` followed with a digit from `0` to `3`, both followed with `h`
- `[0-5]?\dm` - an optional digit from `0` to `5` followed with any digit and `m`
- `)$` - end of the container group and end of string anchor.